# What scope ID is Yahoo expecting for OAuth?

Tags: oauth, yahoo-api

When I configure ASP.NET Core with Yahoo to use the `sdps-r` scope it all works except that it fails within an frustratingly unlogged part of the ASP.NET Core Identity framework - I suspect its because there's no email in the user info.

It seems with Yahoo, the email address is only available in the *extended* profile view, but asking for this profile scope doesn't work at all; Yahoo gives me an error on their OAuth login page.

Using scope `sdpp-r` I get this in the little developer help part of the error.

> Please request scope from registered scopes and submit again

I see nothing wrong with that scope ID. Using `profile` and `email` fail with the same error.

The docs seem simple enough.

https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/social-directory-eol/

Comment: Facing this problem too... looks like the only claim returned in `sub` and no other information.

Comment: FWIW turns out this was due to the permissions set on the oauth application itself.  I did not have `OpenID Connect Permissions` -> `Profile` set as it was hidden.  Had to recreate another application with that set and that fixed it.  Onto the next fire...

Comment: Thanks for stopping by to explain your solution. On to the next fire lol, exactly.